# How to custom button or View when selected same as TouchableOpacity?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I saw in native base of react native have great component is: TouchableOpacity, so i have one question in Android, how can i custom a button or any view like ImageView, TextView... when i selected it look like TouchableOpacity in Android? Thanks

Comment: Taun you can use touch listener on view. on touch event you can set custom effects on view and after releasing touch place view like as before.

Comment: i used this before, but can not exactly like TouchableOpacity

Answer (score 0):

To achieve an almost similar result, try using statelist drawables and animators